# How to have dynamic navigation items in a TWIG template using ZF2 and ZfcTWIG

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2, twig, template-engine

Good day,

I am lost on how to implement what I want in ZF2 since I'm new to it. I have a site that uses ZF2 and ZfcTwig module and I want my TWIG template to have a dynamic navigation based on the settings placed in my mysite.global.php. I want it to read the contents of my config array and create the main navigation using the contents and this will be implemented to all pages of my site.

I already created my layout.twig:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav">
   {% for item in navigation %}

    <li {% if item.active %} class="active" {% endif %}>
       <a href="{{ url(item.route) }}">
       {{ translate(item.name) }}
       </a>
    </li>

   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

and my mysite.global.php

```
return array(
    'mysite' => array(
        'navigation' => array(
            'home' => array(
               'name' => 'Home',
               'route' => 'home',
             ),
            'profile' => array(
               'name' => 'Profile',
               'route' => 'myroute',
               'active' => true
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

This is where I'm lost. How can I transfer my settings to my layout.twig so that every page that uses the layout will use the same items? I tried this code and placed it to my Module.php in the onBootstrap() method:

```
//get my settings and place it to $navigation then

$view = $e->getApplication('application')->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();

$view->navigation = $navigation;
```

but it doesn't work. {{ navigation }} still contains an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which I used:

in module.config.php

```
 'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        'Navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
     ),
  ),

 .....
 'navigation' => array('default' =>array(
    array('label' => 'Home', 'route' => 'home', 'pages' => array(
            array('label' => 'Profile', 'route' => 'myroute'),
          ),
         ),
      ),
    ),
```

And then in layout.twig

```
 {{  navigation('navigation').menu() | raw }}
```

and

```
{{  navigation('navigation').breadcrumbs().render('navigation') | raw }}
```

And that's all, it should work and by the way, it uses [Navigation helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.navigation.html#zend-view-helpers-initial-navigation-navigation)